# Disable Proxy "Automatically detect settings"

Tags: windows-7, proxy, internet

Where can I disable "Automatically detect settings" in the Proxy configuration for all users?

I've configured the following policy:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxySettingsPerUser"=dword:00000000
```

But I can't find the registry setting for HKLM that disables "Automatically detect settings".

Comment: I'm assuming this is for IE and are you using GPOs to do this?

Comment: This is for the system Internet Options (which are used by IE). GPOs: yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group Policy is the best way to do this.

User Configuration
--Windows Settings
----Internet Explorer Maintenance
------Connection/Automatic Browser Configuration
--------Automatically detect configuration settings: set to "Disabled"

Comment: found the GPO setting but forgot to logoff/logon, thanks.

Comment: you can also run "gpupdate /force" instead of logoff/logon!